# Why do I get 'tag not found' error when trying to use VIM help tags

Tags: vim

My vim help tags work intermittently.  Sometimes they're fine, and other times I'll navigate to a tag, press `ctl-]` and get the error message "`E426: tag not found: xx`".

The xx looks wrong.  Right now I'm at a tag 12.1, and it says '`tag not found: 12`'.  I would think it should say 12.1., not 12.

I've run the command `:helptags` ALL, and also the Pathogen command Helptags, to no avail.

My $VIMRUNTIME is

/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/doc and the tags are there.

vim version 8.1 on a Macintosh.

Comment: What plugin are you trying to generate / use tags for?

Comment: The native 'help' tags.  12.1 is the tag in the Chapter 12 of the user's reference manual for vim.

Comment: Does `:echo tagfiles()` list `$VIMRUNTIME/doc`? When `<c-]>` tries `12` instead of `12.1`, it sounds as if your `'iskeyword'` was altered (`:verb set tags?`). Does it work after: `:set tags& iskeyword=!-~,^*,^|,^",192-255` (this should be the default for help buffers)?